# Extracting faded handwriting from lined paper

Tags: background, image-editing

I am trying to create a present for my grandma. She has a letter from my late grandpa that's been on her wall since he passed (7 years ago), but it's fading from the sun.

I have spent hours trying to isolate the text via high contrast and magic wand, but with no luck. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: I would use a brush on a new layer and carefully trace the handwriting.

Comment: Is this a photo? Perhaps a scan would work better.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! If you have a way to get a better image with more even lighting, it would be much easier to clean up.  Without that, @Scott's suggestion of carefully tracing it, or manually deleting around the letters is about your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

With High-pass filtering you can fade the light differences. Better result would be got by shooting the photo in good uniform light or by using a high quality scanner.

When the light differences are faded you can increase contrast with Curves. One result:

[image]

Paper roughness maybe could be faded with clever wavelet detail extracting filters which are available in the free G'MIC filter collection for GIMP, Krita and  Paint.NET. It unfortunately fades also the text which can be seen as paper deformations where the ink has faded. Your light brings them up, scanning maybe couldn't show them.

But filters do not bring back evaporated ink. I guess you should forget extended filtering attempts, a better result is possible by letting a skilled manual text writer make a replica. The right person is the one who would be able to make plausible signature counterfeits. He can have say 100 practicing prints on paper to develop the right movements. It can unfortunately cause some problems between the ears: It's not the original, it's written by someone else - a counterfeit.

**If you have some patience you can try this**:

Draw a clipping path with the pen tool or make a selection with the polygonal lasso tool and copy the text (=ink+deformed area which looks like it was writing) to a new layer.

Process one letter at a time and merge them later. You can easily edit the result later if it doesn't look right.

Adjust the brightness and the color of the copied area with adjustment layers which affect only to the next image layer (=next layer only switch = ON), reduce the opacity of the filtered original:

[image]

This is possible because your photo has generous pixel resolution. Congratulations for it.

You must really analyze how the writing pen has moved. Without understanding it you cannot get it much better than my scratches.